# Beginner: ANTLR does misbehave?

Tags: antlr4

I have a pretty simple grammer to parse Dice-expressions.

```
grammar Dice;
function : ( dice | binaryOp | DIGIT );
binaryOp: dice OPERATOR function | DIGIT OPERATOR function;
dice : DIGIT DSEPERATOR DIGIT EXPLODING?;
DSEPERATOR : ( 'd' | 'D' | 'w' | 'W' );
EXPLODING : ( '*' );
OPERATOR : ( ADD | SUB );
ADD : '+';
SUB : '-';
DIGIT : ('0'..'9')+;
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ; // skip spaces, tabs, newlines
```

It SHOULD parse something like `3D6+2D10` but it doesn't. I get a `no viable alternative at input '2d10'` with this partial result:

```
(function (binaryOp (dice 3 W 6) + (function 2 d 10)))
```

and I do not understand why. Could you please help me understanding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `function` rule is recursive (eventually), you need to add a rule explicitly for the top level so that ANTLR can infer "oh, this top level rule should be the one that implicitly can accept an EOF at the end of input", and then parse from that.

I added a line:

```
start : function ;
```

to your grammar, and can now parse:

```
$ echo "3D6+2D10" | java -cp antlr-4.7.1-complete.jar:. org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig Dice start -tree
(start (function (binaryOp (dice 3 D 6) + (function (dice 2 D 10)))))
```